# SQL Group By Min Date When There Are Multiple Rows With Earliest Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to come up with a query that will return the aggregate data for the earliest orders the customers have placed. Is it possible to do this when there are multiple rows/orders that were placed on the earliest purchase date for a given customer?
For instance, I have these tables:

```
                                 customers
```

| id | name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 2019-07-12 |
| 2 | Jimmy | 2019-01-22 |

```
                                   items
```

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Watch | 200 |
| 2 | Belt | 75 |
| 3 | Wallet | 150 |

```
                                  orders
```

| id | customer_id | item_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2018-08-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2018-08-11 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2019-01-22 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 2019-01-22 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 2019-03-03 |

```
                             expected query
```

| customer_id | name | first_purchase_date | n_items | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 2018-08-01 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | Jimmy | 2019-01-22 | 2 | 350 |

I currently have the following query set up, but this query is grouping by the customer_id such that the total number of items and total price do not reflect the earliest orders.

```sql
SELECT 
    orders.customer_id, 
    customers.name AS name, 
    MIN(orders.created_at) AS first_purchase_date,
    COUNT(*) as n_items,
    SUM(items.price) as total_price
FROM orders
INNER JOIN customers
    ON orders.customer_id = customers.id
INNER JOIN items
    ON orders.item_id = items.id
GROUP BY
    customers.id
```

```
         my incorrect query
```

| customer_id | name | first_purchase_date | n_items | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 2018-08-01 | 2 | 275 |
| 2 | Jimmy | 2019-01-22 | 3 | 425 |

Would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: Other than the `GROUP BY` clause, your query looks correct to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It doesn't seem possible to GROUP BY the earliest date... any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: You are already selecting the `MIN`/earliest date.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am aware - however, columns n_items and total_price are grouped by customer_id. How to group those columns by first_purchase_date?

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

- `cte` will give you the first_purchase_date for each customer id and name
- using that table to find aggregations that matches the customer id and the first_purchase_date

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sH59HOVr)

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    orders.customer_id, 
    customers.name, 
    MIN(orders.created_at) AS first_purchase_date
FROM orders
INNER JOIN customers
    ON orders.customer_id = customers.id
INNER JOIN items
    ON orders.item_id = items.id
GROUP BY
    orders.customer_id,
    customers.name
)

SELECT
    cte.customer_id,
    cte.name,
    cte.first_purchase_date,
    COUNT(orders.item_id) AS n_items,
    SUM(items.price) AS total_price
FROM cte
INNER JOIN orders 
    ON cte.customer_id = orders.customer_id
    AND cte.first_purchase_date = orders.created_at
INNER JOIN items
    ON orders.item_id = items.id
GROUP BY 
    cte.customer_id,
    cte.name,
    cte.first_purchase_date
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select   customer_id
        ,name
        ,created_at as first_purchase_date
        ,count(*)   as n_items
        ,sum(price) as total_price
from    (
         select    o.customer_id
                  ,c.name
                  ,o.created_at
                  ,i.price
                 ,rank() over(partition by o.customer_id order by o.created_at) as rn
         from     orders o join items i on i.id = o.item_id join customers c on c.id = o.customer_id
        ) t
where    rn = 1
group by customer_id, name, created_at
```

| customer_id | name | first_purchase_date | n_items | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sam | 2018-08-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | Jimmy | 2019-01-22 00:00:00 | 2 | 350 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NpFR-jXq?hide=4)